# can't disable youtube embed playlist autoplay

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api

```
<iframe width="763" height="448" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLD7SqVUGDdDBw_xmMKTDF5MlBwys_KlUk&showinfo=0&rel=0&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen style="margin-top:5px; margin-left:5px;"></iframe>
```

When I try it embedding just a video it works, but when I disable autoplay in "embed playlist code" it doesn't work.

In first video it doesn't play automatically but when video ends, it plays the next video, I want it to stop after each video.

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution of this situation, here are the codes that I was searching for and maybe it helps you too.

```
<div id=player></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
      var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;
      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '448',
          width: '763',
          playerVars: {
              'showinfo': 0,
              'controls': 0,
        listType: 'playlist',
        list: 'PLD7SqVUGDdDBw_xmMKTDF5MlBwys_KlUk'
            },
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }

      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        // event.target.playVideo();
      }
      function play_this_video(){
 player.playVideo();
}


      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
          player.stopVideo();
        }
      }
    </script>
```